# Selecting value via substracting another value from a total number

Tags: sql

I am doing simple **mysql** database, and quite knew so sorry if i am bad at formulating this question.

I am asked to make a select statement finding a value in a table, via substracting another value from a total mass.

I have a table called FA:

```
14:0 200
16:0 400
18:0 600
```

so if i have a total mass of `800` i want to find `18:0` by substracting `14:0 (200)`. How can i do this with a select statement?

Hope you guys can help..

Comment: You need to explain in everyday terms what you're trying to accomplish. As stated it is unclear. What is the datatype of the values with colons, e.g. 18:0 ? Are you trying to find the values which, when they are added together, equal a given value? Will there always be only two values added, or could there be three, e.g. if you had a total mass of 1200?   Are you looking for all possible combinations which, when the values are added, could produce a given value?

Comment: Sorry, my first try. 14:0 is the lenght of a fatty acid, 200,400... is the mass of this fatty acid... So further on i am trying to make a database and website, where i will put in a search term like 14:0 which then will calculate the mass of this fatty acid. so it can be substrated from the total mass also given in the search term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can gather from your question:

```
SELECT ID FROM FA WHERE MASS = 800 - (SELECT MASS FROM FA WHERE ID = '14:0')
```

Comment: be so kind to accept the answer, for my benefit and for other readers'.

Comment: IF i had a field with the total mass, can i then make a query to that field instead of writing 800. something like: select id from fa where mass = (select total_mass from lipid where id = '44:2') - (select mass from fa where id = '14:0')

Comment: sure, the only requirement is that the select statement, called a subquery, returns a single value (and it is valid for the expression).